# Integrating SpringSource with XAMPP server

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite, tcserver

I am going to ask if there's a way to add the XAMPP Tomcat Server to the SpringSource Tool Suite's server list under the Server project folder?

Answer (score 0):

As far my knowledge goes, XAMPP stack does not have Tomcat, but an Apache web server.

And for Tomcat, yes you can configure it in STS check out this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-yKgQtpbco). Though video explains it for Eclipse, it's going to be similar for STS too!

Comment: Sorry for the long reply. After seeing the video, I have already configured the Apache Tomcat to my STS but I can't run the project using the that server instead of using the default server provided by VMWare.